# My layout is creating a random margin

Tags: html, css, layout

I am new here and I am facing a very annoying problem which you would think could easily be fixed. But I have been trying to figure this out for the past hour.

Here is my problem, I have drawn a red box around it to indicate the problem -
See below
[image: See below]

Here is the html code -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Darian Steyn">
    <title>BMW</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

                <div id="menu">
                <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"/>
                <ul>
                    <nav>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><span>HOME</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="vehicles.html"><span>VEHICLES</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="mybmw.html"><span>MY BMW</span></a></li>
                    <h1>REGION</h1>
                    </nav>
                </ul>
                <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="slider">
                    <img src="img/bmwConcept2.jpg">
                    <div><img src="img/specials.png"></div>
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Here is the css -

```
    /* my official site styles */

#menu
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #232323;
  float: right; /*Why when I added this here, did it push it to the top*/
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.logo
{
  width: auto;
  height: 80%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.3% 0 0 0.3%;
}

ul
{
  padding: 0.3%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav li
{
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover
{
  color: #1F68A5;
}

nav h1
{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  float: right;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.15em;
  border-color: white;
}

nav h1:hover
{
  color: #1F68A5;
  border-color: #1F68A5;
}

#slider
{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;

}

#slider img:first-child
{
  height: 550px;
  width:70%;
  float: left;

}

#slider div
{
  width:30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2em;

}

.fix
{
  clear: both;
}
```

I Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Darian Steyn">
    <title>BMW</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
    #menu
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #232323;
  float: right; /*Why when I added this here, did it push it to the top*/
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.logo
{
  width: auto;
  height: 80%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.3% 0 0 0.3%;
}

ul
{
  padding: 0.3%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav li
{
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover
{
  color: #1F68A5;
}

nav h1
{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  float: right;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.15em;
  border-color: white;
}

nav h1:hover
{
  color: #1F68A5;
  border-color: #1F68A5;
}

#slider
{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;

}

#slider img:first-child
{
  width:70%;

}

#slider div
{
  width:30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2em;

}

.fix
{
  clear: both;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

                <div id="menu">
                <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"/>
                <ul>
                    <nav>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><span>HOME</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="vehicles.html"><span>VEHICLES</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="mybmw.html"><span>MY BMW</span></a></li>
                    <h1>REGION</h1>
                    </nav>
                </ul>
                <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="slider">
                    <img src="img/bmwConcept2.jpg" style="width:70%">
                   <img src="img/specials.png" style="width:30%;float:right;">
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My good man. You have literally fixed it. Could you please explain to me what I was doing wrong. I would love to know for next time!

Comment: One image with div and another one without div. I just removed and set width to those images.

Answer (score 0):

This is badly formatted, dunno if it is the fix to your problem, but needs to be changed.

```
<ul>
                <nav>
                <li><a href="index.html"><span>HOME</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="vehicles.html"><span>VEHICLES</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="mybmw.html"><span>MY BMW</span></a></li>
                <h1>REGION</h1>
                </nav>
            </ul>
```

should be at least this:

```
                <nav>
<ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><span>HOME</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="vehicles.html"><span>VEHICLES</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="mybmw.html"><span>MY BMW</span></a></li>
</ul>
                <h1>REGION</h1>
                </nav>
```

Without linking to the site and seeing the size of the images, I think your problem is with the CSS that deals with the slider.

```
#slider img:first-child
{
  height: 550px;
  width:70%;
  float: left;

}

#slider div
{
  width:30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2em;

}
```

I would start with removing the width and margin settings as I expect that is causing the problem and remove the first child part.  First focus on getting the slider working as per the maker of the sliders css, then add your own.

Comment: Hi there!
Thank you for the reply, I am a web student currently and I am just starting out so excuse the mistakes haha. The image on the left is 1680w × 756 and the image on the right is 700wx757. Is there a way I could send you the html file? I appreciate the help